# Use reactive "if" statements in R Shiny

Tags: r, loops, shiny

Below are the headers of my dataframe (appliance) along with it's structure.

```
      Home Season Day Timein24 countRun Run
19262    1 Autumn   1        1        8  NA
19263    1 Autumn   1        1        8  NA
19264    1 Autumn   1        1        8  NA
19265    1 Autumn   1        1        8  NA
19266    1 Autumn   1        2        8  NA
19267    1 Autumn   1        2        8  NA
19268    1 Autumn   1        2        8  NA
19293    1 Autumn   1        2        8  NA
19290    1 Autumn   1        3        8  NA
19295    1 Autumn   1        3        8  NA
19271    1 Autumn   1        3        8  NA
19294    1 Autumn   1        3        8  NA
19272    1 Autumn   1        4        8  NA
19273    1 Autumn   1        4        8  NA
19274    1 Autumn   1        4        8  NA
19275    1 Autumn   1        4        8  NA
19236    1 Autumn   1        5        8  NA
19237    1 Autumn   1        5        8  NA
19278    1 Autumn   1        5        8  NA
19279    1 Autumn   1        5        8  NA
```

str(appliance)

```
   'data.frame':    51072 obs. of  6 variables:
     $ Home    : Factor w/ 19 levels "1","2","3","5",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ Season  : chr  "Autumn" "Autumn" "Autumn" "Autumn" ...
     $ Day     : Factor w/ 7 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ Timein24: Factor w/ 12 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
     $ countRun: num  8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
     $ Run     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

in $Season, I've four seasons and then in $countRun the values are 4,8,12. Also pasting the UI and Server of the R Shiny I've tried so far. I'm facing issues with the "if" statement. Please see:

```
ui = navbarPage("Flexible Demand", 
                tabPanel("Appliance1", 
                         fixedRow(column(width = 12, offset = 5, titlePanel("Appliance1"))),
                         fixedRow(column(width = 6, selectizeInput("Home", label = "Select Home",
                                                                   choices = c(sort(unique(appliance$Home))),
                                                                   selected = c(sort(unique(appliance$Home)))[1],
                                                                   multiple = F, width = "100%")),
                                  column(width = 6, selectizeInput("Season", label = "Select Season",
                                                                   choices = c(sort(unique(appliance$Season))),
                                                                   selected = c(sort(unique(appliance$Season)))[1],
                                                                   multiple = F, width = "100%"))),
                         fixedRow(column(width = 6, sliderInput("Day1C", label = "Day 1 - Hour to Run",
                                                                min = 1,max = 12, value = 2)), 
                                  column(width = 6, selectizeInput("Day1", label = "Day 1 - Duration (Hours)",
                                                                   choices = c(sort(unique(appliance$countRun))),
                                                                   selected = c(sort(unique(appliance$countRun)))[1],
                                                                   multiple = F, width = "100%")),
                                  mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("day1")))))

server = function(input, output, session){
  output$day1 = DT::renderDataTable({
    day1 = reactive({appliance[appliance$Home %in% input$Home &
                                  appliance$Season %in% input$Season,]})
    if (appliance$Timein24 != input$Day1C) {
      appliance$Run=0
    } else{appliance$Run=1}
    day1()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What I'm trying to achieve by this is to have values of Run reactive based on whatever I choose in sliderInput "Day1C" and column "Timein24". for e.g. if I choose my "Day 1- Hour to Run" i.e. sliderInput "Day1C" as 2 then the Run for **all** 2s under "Timein24" column of the dataframe should be `1` and for others it should be `0`.

I hope I'm making sense. Let me know if you want any further details.

Comment: (1) Your `if` is just wrong R code: `appliance$Timein24 != ...` is not length 1, and everything inside an `if` condition must always be exactly length 1. Do you mean to use `all`, `any`, or `[1]` in there somewhere? (2) You cannot nest reactive blocks so your definition of `day1` should be on its own and then `day1()` referenced within the `renderDataTable` reactive block. (3) The effects of your `if` code have zero impact on the data displayed within the `DT`, since it is affecting `appliance` but `day1` is already defined.

Comment: @r2evans It should ideally take `all`. can you help in improving the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shot, not fully tested:

```
server = function(input, output, session){
  day1 = reactive({
    req(input$Home, input$Season)
    appliance[appliance$Home %in% input$Home &
              appliance$Season %in% input$Season,]
  })
  output$day1 = DT::renderDataTable({
    req(day1(), input$Day1C)
    x <- day1()
    x$Run <- ifelse(x$Timein24 == input$Day1C, 1, 0)
    x
  })
}
```